# insert_id as a href?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hopefully a very easy question, but I am stuck.
I have a page for creating a new user on my system, after the user is created I display the users id.

```
printf("New member added. The new member ID is %d \n", $mysqli->insert_id );
```

Can someone tell me how to turn this into a link ? I want to be able to click on the ID and be taken to /display=*ID number*.php
Ive tried putting it into a a href but it keeps failing.

Was thinking something like

```
 printf("New member added. The new member ID is <a href="display=%d"> \n", $mysqli- >insert_id );
```

Thanks

Comment: what did you try to put it into a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to put the HTML for the link into the printf statement, with the `%d` where you want the ID to be in the URL. Just make sure the quotes match; that you aren't using double quotes inside the double quoted string without escaping them.

Comment: Got it ... was my quotes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create link like this `<a href="display=<?php echo $mysqli->insert_id; ?>.php">ID Link</a>`

In your case you need escape `"` or use `'`

`printf("New member added. The new member ID is <a href=\"display=%d\">Link</a> \n", $mysqli- >insert_id);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it in the URL using GET parameters:

```
?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

Then in PHP you can read the values of these params like:

```
$_GET['param1']
$_GET['param2']
$_GET['param3']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php printf("New member added. The new member ID is <a href=\"display=%d\">Link</a> \n", "$mysqli- >insert_id");
?>
```

I tested.Itz working fine.